# Yup validation schema object conditional validation

Tags: reactjs, validation, conditional-statements, formik, yup

I want to baisically say if type = 1 then validate the membership object , did try it with .when() but had to do it with eacth of the object (only when type =1 then validate

```
 validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                        //General
                        name: Yup.string().min(3).required('Name is required.'),
                        email: Yup.string().email().required('Email is required.'),
                        contactNo: Yup.number().required('Number is required.'),
                        address: Yup.string().required('Address is required.'),
                        country: Yup.string().required('Country is required.'),
    
    
                        memberShip: Yup.object() 
                        .shape({
//Something like this
if(type ===1){
                            memberShipNo: Yup.string().required('MemberShip Number is required.'),
                            memberShipStart: Yup.string().required( 'MemberShip Number is required.'),
                            fee: Yup.string().required('MemberShip Number is required.')},
                        }),
                        
                     
    
                        verified: Yup.bool(),
                    })}
```

Comment: Not exactly clear on your question but you said `type=1` but I dont see `type` field in your schema. I think you want conditional validation based on certain other field selection, please clarify

Comment: Hi made some edits hope this helps

Comment: the type validation is a prop im getting

Comment: so `type` is a prop based on which you are requiring `membership` object otherwise its optional?

Comment: Yes so if type =2 or something dont validate the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach your issue for rendering conditional field is by using ternary and spreading. This solution do require little bit of repeating code and there may be other (better) ways though which is up to you to keep investigating if you want better solution.

In this example if `type === 1` then all fields are `required` else not required but optional.

```
 memberShip: Yup.object()
  .shape({
    ...(type === 1 ? {
      memberShipNo: Yup.string().required('MemberShip Number is required.'),
      memberShipStart: Yup.string().required('MemberShip Number is required.'),
      fee: Yup.string().required('MemberShip Number is required.')
    } : {
      memberShipNo: Yup.string(),
      memberShipStart: Yup.string(),
      fee: Yup.string()
    }),
  }),
```

Comment: I keep getting errors  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: @ChrisJnrPotgieter fixed it